# NSString Library... Anyone know of a helper library for NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

Coming from a ruby background, I'm wishing NSString had some convenient methods like the following:

```
[@"John" contains:@"ohn"] => BOOL
[@"1,2,3,4," split:@","] => NSArray
```

Anyone know of such an NSString helper library?

Comment: NSString already has quite a lot of convenient methods implemented for it.  The full reference is: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some "quickies" for the NSString class, quite a handy reference to keep around: http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSString

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
BOOL contains = ([@"John" rangeOfString:@"ohn"].length == 0 ? NO : YES);
NSArray *array = [@"1,2,3,4" componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:

```
NSString *list = @"Norman, Stanley, Fletcher";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000149-CJBBGBAI

```
NSString *searchString = @"age";

NSString *beginsTest = @"Agencies";
NSRange prefixRange = [beginsTest rangeOfString:searchString
    options:(NSAnchoredSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)];

// prefixRange = {0, 3}
```